# AutoMapper map nested list of objects within list of objects

Tags: c#, automapper

I have these classes:

```
public class Course
{
public int CourseId;
public List<Exam> Exams;
}

public class Exam
{
public int ExamId;
public float Score;
}
```

These are my ViewModels:

```
public class CourseVM
{
public int CourseId;
public List<ExamVM> Exams;
}

public class ExamVM
{
public int ExamId;
public float Score;
public bool Selected;
}
```

This is the code I'm using to map a `List` of `Courses` to a `List` of `CourseVM`. I'm having a problem trying to map the property `Exams` within `CourseVM` since is a `ViewModel` too(`ExamVM`). Any idea on how to do this using `AutoMapper`?

```
examsVM = _mapper.Map<List<Course>, List<CourseVM>>(coursesList);
```

**UPDATE**
Mapping rules:

```
CreateMap<Course, CourseVM>()
```

Comment: Are mapper rules specified?

Comment: @feihoa yes, added then in the question too, trying different things in that direction now

Comment: CreateMap<Exam, ExamVM>() is specified as well? Also, try to make all the fields properties: public int CourseId {get; set;}

Comment: @feihoa tried that and worked, just came back to put an answer and saw your comment, feel free to add it as an answer and I'll choose it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that proper config is specified:

```
CreateMap<Exam, ExamVM>();
```

Try to make properties from the fields:

```
public int CourseId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you write MappingProfile?

If u want to use automapper u have to tell him how u wanna map.

there is example of automapper profile:

> ```
> public class RestaurantMappingProfile: Profile
>     {
>         public RestaurantMappingProfile()
>         {
>             CreateMap<Restaurant, RestaurantDto>()
>                 .ForMember(m => m.City, c => c.MapFrom(s => s.Address.City))
>                 .ForMember(m => m.Street, c => c.MapFrom(s => s.Address.Street))
>                 .ForMember(m => m.ZipCode, c => c.MapFrom(s => s.Address.ZipCode));
>            
>             CreateMap<Dish, DishDto>();
>            
>             CreateMap<CreateRestaurantDto, Restaurant>()
>                 .ForMember(r => r.Address, c => c.MapFrom(dto => new Address()
>                         { City = dto.City, ZipCode = dto.ZipCode, Street = dto.Street }));
>             
>             CreateMap<CreateDishDto, Dish>();
>         
>         
>         
>         }
> ```